# Apply divergences between two "relative frequency distributions", instead of between two "probability distributions"

Tags: distributions, distance, similarities, frequency, divergence

**Introduction.** Recalling that:

- The frequency is the number of observations of a specific outcome.
- The relative frequency is a proportion of all observations (frequency / total observations).
- A "frequency distribution" or "relative frequency distribution" is a way of displaying observed samples from experiments.
- A "probability distribution" is a theoretical model for an experiment.
- Jensen Shannon Divergence and Kullback-Leibler Divergence are usually calculated between two "probability distributions"

**Question 1.** Can we apply Jensen Shannon Divergence and Kullback-Leibler Divergence between two "relative frequency distributions", instead of between two "probability distributions"?

**Question 2.** In general, for any type of distance, or divergence, or similarity functions that were originally designed for "probability distributions", can we apply the same distances, divergences, or similarities between two "relative frequency distributions"?

Comment: All "relative frequency distributions" are *a fortiori* probability distributions.  Mathematically, there's no obstacle to calculating with them.  What, then, is your *statistical* question, if any?

Comment: Aren't my questions related to probability and statistics? You already gave me the answer I needed. If you want to put it as an Answer, I will accept it - Thanks a lot @whuber!

Comment: "Can we calculate" is, strictly speaking, a question about *arithmetic.*  If you mean something different than that, then please edit your question to clarify its statistical intent.

Comment: Better now? However, I can use different terms, such as "apply", "use", "employ", or "calculate", or whatever - The meaning is the same. In addition: "can we calculate" is not "How can we calculate", that would be a question about an arithmetic action. This is a question about the conditions for applying, or not, a (or more) statistical quantity(ies).

Comment: They are all vague: they lack any indication of why you might be asking this question, why you might be "applying" such functions, and why you believe there's any distinction between applying them to a distribution that is called "relative frequency" instead of "probability."

Comment: Looks like a review of Nature. I do not need to give any further explanation since it is a self-consistent and self-explanatory question. In addition, it is not necessary to give a reason for a question on this forum. Also, those terms are not vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relative frequency distribution can be referred to as an observed or empirical probability distribution. (See Chapter 2 of Mohr, D.L., Wilson, W.J. & Freund, R.J. (2021). Statistical Methods, 4th Ed. https://doi.org/10.1016/C2019-0-02521-6).

Due to this, it is reasonable to apply distances/divergences (such as JSD and KLD) between two relative frequency distributions. So to answer your questions - given they are of a closed form - both can be simply answered "Yes".

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks a lot! :-)